# Pair of linear equation in two variables

Tags: quadratics

This is from a text book:-
"*The general form of a linear equation in two variables is $ax + by + c = 0$ or, $ax + by = c$  where $a, b, c$ are real numbers such that $a ≠ 0$, $b≠0$ and $x, y$ are variables.*
**(we often denote the condition $a$ and $b$ are not both zero by $a^2+b^2≠0$.)"**
I don’t understand this last condition.
How can we say that $a^2+b^2≠0$ represents the condition that $a$ and $b$ are not both zero.
Let $a = 0, b = 1$, then also this condition fulfills.
Any help?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ not both zero - this statement means that both the quantities $a$ and $b$ are not allowed to be $0$, i.e. $a=0, b=0$ is not allowed. That tantamounts to saying that $a^2+b^2\ne 0$ since $a^2+b^2=0 \iff a=0=b$ for real $a,b$.

Comment: $a=0$ and $b=1$ is an example where $a$ and $b$ are not both $0$

Comment: [A] ***such that $a≠0$, $b≠0$***.    
This statement reflects the fact that both $a$ and $b$ are non zero.    
[B] **$a^2+b^2\neq 0$**.    
This statement reflects the fact that one of $a$ and $b$ can be zero.    
Isn't there a contradiction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a$ and $b$ are both zero $\iff$ $a=b=0$, so
$a$ and $b$ are NOT both zero $\iff$ at least one of $a,b$ is not $0$
which is equivalent to $a^2+b^2=0$ in the case that $a,b$ are both real numbers.

Answering to your comment, yes, you are right. Maybe a better way to write in an inequality is $(a,b)\neq(0,0)$ instead of "$a\neq0,b\neq0$"

Comment: (a,b)≠(0,0); I am not familiar with this notation. What does it mean?

Comment: @ShekharMalhotra Geometrically you can think of it as 'the point (a,b) is not the same point as the origin'. Algebraically, $a\neq0$ AND $b\neq0$. In normal English words, '$a,b$ are not both zero.

Answer (score 0):

Generally words "together", "both" and comma sign "," is used for logical operation AND (conjunction), denoted  by $x \land y$. So $$(a \ne 0, b \ne 0) \Leftrightarrow (a \ne 0 \land b \ne 0) \Leftrightarrow (a^2+b^2 \ne 0)$$